# Attempt to combine similar entries in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I currently have two tables in Microsoft access containing data from two separate days. The majority of the data is not important, but there are two naming categories (Name1, Name2 for the purpose of this post). I am attempting to check if all of Name1/Name2 pairings in Table1 are also in Table2. If any are not, I want to add them to a different table, MissingData.

This is complicated by the size of the databases and the fact that duplicates of one name are common. For instance, a simplified view of the tables would look something like this:

Table1 -
Name1 / Other Data / Name2 // A     /    2       / Z // A     /   Apple    / Y //B     /  Bat       / Y

Table2 - 
Name1 / Other Data / Name2 // A     /    Orange  / Z // B     /    56      / Y //A     /     Random / X

In this case, I would want the function to place the A/Apple/Y line from Table1 into the MissingData table.

Here is the code I have so far. It almost works but has one small problem; duplicate instance of Name1 will come up as missing if the order of the matching Name2 data is not the same as in Table2. For instance, if Table1 has A/X, A/Y, and A/Z, and Table2 has A/Z, A/X, and A/Y, the data is reported as missing (Note - I am not certain the order is the culprit, but that is my guess).

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Public Sub SaleSorter()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dest As String
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim sqry7 As String
sqry7 = "INSERT INTO MissingData(dest) SELECT * FROM Tester1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tester2 WHERE Tester1.[Name1] = Tester2.[Name1] AND Tester1.[Name2] = Tester2.[Name2] )"
DoCmd.RunSQL sqry7

End Sub
```

*dest is simply a string of all the field names in the table, in an earlier portion of the function I omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [EXCEPT and INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx). You can use EXCEPT to determine what names are fist table and not the second table, while INTERSECT would return only what names are in both the first and second table.

```
-- this assumes table3 is your 'missing persons' table

-- add anyone that is in table1 and not in table2
INSERT INTO #table3
SELECT Name1, Name2 FROM #table1
EXCEPT 
SELECT Name1, Name2 FROM #table2

-- add anyone that is in table2 and not in table1
INSERT INTO #table3
SELECT Name1, Name2 FROM #table2
EXCEPT 
SELECT Name1, Name2 FROM #table1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I am getting an error that says there is a syntax error in the FROM clause. Some quick googling told me that the Except clause cannot be used in Microsoft Access. Is that true?

Comment: Sorry, looks like you correct - it works in SQL but not Access. My mistake. I think the "Find UnMatched" feature might be a substitute worth looking into: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/compare-two-tables-and-find-records-without-matches-HA010205132.aspx